# 'full-calendar' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

Hey I am new to Angular...
So far I want to try out the fullcalendar. I try to run the module before and it works. However today I created a new Project and just followed the Steps which are described in the angular doc Furthermore I went trough all the steps in the fullcalendar doc but it is still not working.

this is the error i am getting:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'full-calendar' is not a known element:
1. If 'full-calendar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'full-calendar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1 <full-calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" [plugins]="calendarPlugins"></full-calendar>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FullCalendarModule} from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FullCalendarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'nachweis-frontend';
  calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin];
}
```

app.component.html

```
<full-calendar [plugins] = "calendarPlugins"></full-calendar>
```

Here is also my angular json. I did no changes here:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "nachweis-frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/nachweis-frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "nachweis-frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "nachweis-frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "nachweis-frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "nachweis-frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "nachweis-frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "nachweis-frontend",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include a sample of your code where you are trying to use fullcalendar, so we can help you figure out where it's going wrong

Comment: @awarrier99 ok done do you need more code snippets?

Comment: Can you include your `app.component.scss` and global stylesheets as well? Maybe `angular.json` too. Also, what happens if you try changing the selector in your `app.component.ts` file from `'app-root'` to `'full-calendar'`. Does it work then? I know their docs say otherwise, but typically the selector value is the name of the component that should be used in the template

Comment: Actually, never mind what I suggested about changing the selector in `app.component.ts`, I was thinking of your component rather than the imported full-calendar component

Comment: @awarrier99 my app.component.css is empty. As it is described in the fullcalendar doc I just added  import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css'; import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css'; to style.css

Comment: Hmm I'm honestly lost as to where this could be going wrong. Any chance you could host your entire project setup in a GitHub for a little while so I can look around and see if there's anything out of place (as long as there's nothing you'd like to keep private or something)? Just so I don't have to keep asking you to see individual files and also so I can try it out myself and play around with it

Comment: https://github.com/swone1990/nachweis-frontend

Comment: Thank you. No there is nothing to hide i just wanted to start learning angular and had a simple project in mind :)

Comment: No problem. So the code you had in the GitHub hadn't already included any of the full-calendar code (so you probably just hadn't pushed your code up yet), but once I followed the guide I was able to get it to display properly. I can push whatever I have to a branch called `test` if you want

Comment: would be greate thank you

Comment: I just pushed my new version including the full-calender

Comment: Ok cool I'll take a look at that to see if I can figure out the difference. Also I may need to be added as a collaborator to push, it said permission denied when I tried

Comment: i added you as a collaborator

Comment: I just posted an answer with this as well, but it turns out a couple of things were missing from your `app.module.ts` file on GitHub, even though it was there in the version of the file you posted here

Comment: Still won't let me push for some reason, but if you make those changes I mentioned in my answer to your `app.module.ts` file it should work properly (as it did for me). Let me know if you still have problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your GitHub code, and I know it was in the file you posted in your post, but for some reason this was missing from the `app.module.ts` in your GitHub:

`import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular';`

and

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FullCalendarModule
],
```

I tested it out on my machine, so as long as you have all the `npm` packages in your `package.json` installed, your code should now work

Comment: Okay i dont get it. It was not there but now it works. Thank you for you greate efford. Love u ^^

Answer (score 0):

maybe try with these .. (as doc says at : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular)

```
npm install --save @fullcalendar/angular @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/daygrid
```

2-) after that import the module in your app.module.ts file the `FullCalendarModule`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular'; // for FullCalendar!
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FullCalendarModule // for FullCalendar!
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3-) now you have the fullcalendar in. your app so try in your component in:

a) `html`

```
<full-calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" [plugins]="calendarPlugins"></full-calendar>
```

b) in `ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'; //< import. it

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin]; // important!

}
```

4-) Be carefully ..as doc says ... import. the css `MANUALLY` in your css(or scss file) put:

```
 @import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: this is exactly what i have done. But it is not working

Comment: double check if the node_modules are installed .. and maybe import js files in angular.json file in scripts section